# Compare template helper values in Spacebars {{#if}} block

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I need to compare two template helper values that are located in nested templates. I was wondering if there is an easy way to compare two template helpers (one from the parent template) in an {{#if}} statement like so:

```
{{#each bids}}
  {{#if bid.price===../job.price}}
    <span>some text</span>
  {{else}}
    <span>some other text</span>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

If you can't do this, I guess the other option is to use Template.parentData in a new template inside the each block? I'm not opposed to this, just the way I outlined above would be much faster and simpler if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: So I ended up getting my code to work by running bids.forEach(function(bid) { bid.match = bid.price===Template.currentData().job.price; }); in my bids helper, effectively adding the match condition to the bids helper. I'd still be interested to know if spacebars can handle comparison logic or not. From everything I've searched for, it doesn't look like it does.

Comment: You could also just register an equals function `Template.registerHelper('equals', function(a, b) {return a===b;})`, but I like Peppe L-G's idea of registering underscore better.

Comment: Agreed, it's more elegant and flexible.

Comment: raix:handlebar-helpers serves a similar purpose

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```js
Template.registerHelper('_', function(){
    return _
})
```

```html
{{#each bids}}
  {{#if _.isEqual bid.price ../job.price}}
    <span>some text</span>
  {{else}}
    <span>some other text</span>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

As a bonus, you not only get `_.isEqual`, but all _.* functions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are right, spacebars doesn't support logical statements in the `#if` condition. But you can easily define a new block helper that does:

```
HandlebarsRegister.registerHelper('ifx', function(conditional, options) {
    var truthValue = false;
    try {
        truthValue = eval(conditional);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Exception in #ifx evaluation of condition: ",
                    conditional, e);
    }
    if (truthValue) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

and then use

```
{{#each bids}}
  {{#ifx "bid.price===../job.price"}}
    <span>some text</span>
  {{else}}
    <span>some other text</span>
  {{/ifx}}
{{/each}}
```

The only downside is that you will need to write your condition as a string and `eval` is not exactly elegant. But hey, it works.